# One Query to delete table row based from other table value

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am using Php my admin I would really appreciate any advice or help I am trying to delete address that is not in use based on columns from another table and can delete also if not found in other column value

I have 2 tables like this:

**tbladdress**

```
id         Address 
1222       add1
1332       add2
1555       add3
1776       add4
```

**tblcx**

```
name       location    Status
ana        1222        completed
ema        1332        used
ada        1332        completed
```

I want to delete rows that from tbladdress where id is equals to tblcx location which tblcx Status is completed while if tblcx Status is used cannot do any deletion

**desired output**

```
tbladdress

id         Address 
1332       add2
```

id 1332 were not deleted because it is still being used by another customer
1555 and 1776 were deleted because it is not exist in other table 1222 were deleted because status is completed

I am using this query

```
DELETE t1
FROM tbladdress t1 
    INNER JOIN tblcx t2 
        ON t1.ID = t2.location and t2.Status = 'Completed';
```

It is working fine but I also wanted to delete the id that is not found in tblcxlocation

I wanted it like to be in one query  I would really appreciate any advice or help

```
DELETE FROM tbladdress
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM tblcx
    WHERE (tbladdress.id != tblcx.location)
);
```

Comment: Can't you do `DELETE t1, t2
FROM tbladdress t1 
    INNER JOIN tblcx t2 
        ON t1.ID = t2.location and t2.Status = 'Completed';` ??

Answer (score 1):

You can use `EXISTS` to check if a record with status `'used'` exists in `tblscx` for an address. All addresses where no such record exists, are the one you want to delete, I suppose. So negate the expression with `NOT`.

```
DELETE FROM tbladdress
            WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                     FROM tblscx
                                     WHERE tblscx.location = tbladdress.id
                                           AND tblscx.status = 'used');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `LEFT JOIN` instead, and check for `t2.location` being `NULL` (i.e. there is no matching record for `t1.ID`):

```
DELETE t1
FROM tbladdress t1 
LEFT JOIN tblcx t2 ON t1.ID = t2.location
WHERE t2.Status = 'Completed' OR t2.location IS NULL
```